# How can I import a online JavaDoc to Intellij?

Tags: intellij-idea, javadoc

I want to import a [JavaDoc from the Web](https://api.cavecloud.net/docs/cloudapi/) to Intellij. How can I do this?
I already tried [this](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/viewing-reference-information.html#external-docs), but IntelliJ still marks it as false.

Comment: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/viewing-reference-information.html#external-docs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a API-Folder during the Install-Process of the Cloud.